# How to find the integral of $\lim_ \ x^2 \arcsin(x^3)/\sqrt{1-x^6}\ dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I could really use some help trying to find this integral please.

$$\int \frac{x^2\arcsin(x^3)}{\sqrt{1-x^6}} dx$$

Comment: I think you have a superfluous "lim" there.

Answer (score 4):

The derivative of $\arcsin(x^3)$ is $3x^2/\sqrt{1-x^6}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $u$-sub is your friend. Let $u = \arcsin(x^3)$. What is $du$?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that if $\;f\;$ is a differential function, we have that

$$\int\frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\frac{\arcsin^2 x}2+C\implies \int\frac{f'(x)\arcsin f(x)}{\sqrt{1-f(x)^2}}dx=\frac{\arcsin^2f(x)}2+C $$

solve your problem now with $\;f(x)=x^3\;$